# OneDrive signing in with acces token

Tags: c#, windows-7-x64

at the moment i am accessing OneDrive via manually signing in with a webbrowser (WinForm). But I want to create a Service which synchronizes my data on OneDrive all x-minutes. So when i start my computer the service starts and should already be logged in. Is there any way to save access token? Because the access token expires after an hour as far is I know, and i have not found out the clue how to refreh the access token with a refresh token yet. But also if I can refresh my access token, wouldn't it be expired? I don't think that over night my refresh token will be valid to request a new access token? And  the refresh token isn't valid forever isn't it?
I hope someone is familiar with this topic and understands my question. I am really stuck here at the moment so I would be really thankful for an answer.

edit:

Ok finally understand refresh token and its behaviour/expire time.
The bigger problem still exists, how do i get an access token through refresh token?
And how do i login with access token ?

Comment: onedrive sdk won't help?

Comment: I am using live sdk already, I hope there is a way to do what i want this live sdk, problem is I haven't found out yet.